# How to know which was my previous tab bar view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say i have 4 tab bar view controllers. I am programatically coming to 2nd tab bar view controller after doing a function in 3rd tab bar view controller. How can i know am coming from 3rd tab bar view controller when i reach 2nd tab bar view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily track that via the [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods:

For example, you could implement `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` and check the tab bar controller's `selectedIndex` or `selectedViewController` properties (which will still contain the *old* value, because that method is called before the change).

Alternatively, you could just implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` and keep track of the last selected view controller/index yourself.

Keep in mind, though, that both methods are only called for **user-initiated** tab changes, not those done programmatically.